# How to execute command with parameters?

Tags: java, parameters, exec, runtime.exec

How am I to execute a command in Java with parameters?

I've tried

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"php","/var/www/script.php -m 2"});
```

which doesn't work.

```
String[] options = new String[]{"option1", "option2"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command", options);
```

This doesn't work as well, because the `m` parameter is not specified.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

See if this works (sorry can't test it right now)

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"php","/var/www/script.php", "-m", "2"});
```

Comment: This should mention that this is important to set one `String` per command; parameter or value. So `"-m 2"` might not work. This need to be `"-m",  "2"`

Answer (score 26):

Use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead of `Runtime#exec()`.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("php", "/var/www/script.php", "-m 2");
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: If that doesn't work: `new ProcessBuilder("php", "/var/www/script.php", "-m", "2");`

Answer (score 1):

The following should work fine.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("php /var/www/script.php -m 2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is java code for executing python script with java.

#### ProcessBuilder:

- First argument is path to virtual environment
- Second argument is path to python file
- Third argument is any argumrnt you want to pass to python script

```java
public class JavaCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String lines = null;
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/home/env-scrapping/bin/python",
                "/home/Scrapping/script.py", "arg1");
        Process process = builder.start();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        while ((lines = reader.readLine())!=null) {
            System.out.println("Line: " + lines);
        }
    }
}
```

First is virtual environment path

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).