# Escape whitespace in filepath

Tags: java, windows, exec, whitespace, filepath

I am writing a small Java Application and I am having problems with a filepath.

I want to execute a batch file with

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start c:\program files\folder\file.bat");`

But now Java cries because of the whitespace in the filepath.

How can I escape it?

EDIT:

Ok, thank you for the answers guys. 
But I just ran into a new problem:

If I start the .bat this way it just opens a cmd window and nothing happens. But if I move the .bat into c:/folder/ without spaces it works...the .bat itself is fine too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute command with parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134486/how-to-execute-command-with-parameters)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can avoid any problems like this by using the [Runtime#exec](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) that takes a String[]:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cmd", "/c", "start", "c:\\program files\\folder\\file.bat"});
```

That way you don't have to worry about quoting the file names. However, you still have to worry about quoting \ in the file names.

Answer (score 1):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \"c:/program files/folder/file.bat\"");
```

should work

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Runtime.getRuntime it is better to use [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

That way you can have something like:

```
List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
command.add("first-arg");
command.add("second arg with spaces") //this one will be accepted as a single argument,   eventhough it has spaces
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution for windows 7 at least:

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("my_program_name.exe \"" + namefile+"\");
```

The idea is to put namefile between the character ".

Answer (score 0):

I think it cries because of the unescaped back slashes in your string. Quote the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Put quotes around and quote backslashes:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \"c:\\program files\\folder\\file.bat\"");
```

Comment: It worked only for windows, how could we cross the three platform about macos, ubuntu, windows?

Answer (score 0):

surround the filepath with `"`

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \"c:\\program files\\folder\\file.bat\"");
```

and properly escape the `\` in the path as well

Answer (score 0):

you have to escape the slashes so `\\` and in windows white space are escaped with `%20`. I don't know about other system, could work. But first thing do the `\\`.