# How Run file path with space

Tags: java, path

I have code :

```
String[] cmd = {"cmd", 
                 "/C", 
                 "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\WINWORD.exe",
                 "/mOpenPage", 
                 "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\QuanLyBaiGiang\\Lop 6\\Abc.doc"};

Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Not Run
BUT "\Lop6" ==> run good !
you can fix error "\Lop 6\" ==> run

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escape whitespace in filepath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596235/escape-whitespace-in-filepath)

Answer (score 1):

Multiple tokens passed the the `CMD` Windows shell cause the tokens to be demilited by space character, even if surrounded by quotes. As you don't need to execute any shell commands here you can remove the shell command arguments:

```
String[] cmd = { "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\WINWORD.exe",
                 "/mOpenPage", 
                 "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\QuanLyBaiGiang\\Lop 6\\Abc.doc"};
```