# Calling Unix command from Java

Tags: java, unix, grep, exec, pipe

How do I execute the Unix `grep` program to search for patterns in a set of files by calling that command from inside a Java program?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you look at the questions in the "Related" section? What exactly are you having a problem with?

Comment: The frequency of these sorts of questions suggests several interesting points. First, Java doesn’t go out of its way to make it easy to call “alien” (read: non-Java) programs and process their output. Second, this is something that people nevertheless end up wanting to do often enough. Other conclusions are possible but suspect, like Java getting low marks for playing well and getting along with others, and whether the querent has chosen the wrong language for the task. Those are facile conclusions to reach, but are potentially deceptive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute command with parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134486/how-to-execute-command-with-parameters)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Runtime.exec`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec)

> ```
> public Process exec(String[] cmdarray,
>                     String[] envp,
>                     File dir)
>                     throws IOException
> ```
>
> Executes the specified command and arguments in a separate process with the specified environment and working directory.

EDIT:  As Joachim and andypandy point out, [`ProcessBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#command%28java.lang.String...%29) has a more flexible interface, and if you're running on JDK7 or later provides support for setting up sub-process file descriptors.

> Starting a new process which uses the default working directory and environment is easy:
>
> ```
>  Process p = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg").start();
> ```

Comment: I'd suggest using `ProcessBuilder` instead: it has the exact same functionality, but a *much* nicer API.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I am new to invoke a process from a java class, and I have used Runtime.exec. Why are you saying that ProcessBuilder has a "much nicer API"? In what terms?

Comment: @AlbertS: several things: You can *configure* the `ProcessBuilder` by using several method calls with very speaking method names (`.directory(new File("/tmp"))` speaks very clearly), you can simply *leave out* the method calls you don't care about instead of having to pass `null` to some method at some position, you can sane redirects (since Java 1.7) and you can manipulate the starting environment variables of the process using a simple `Map` (for example in the `Runtime.exec()` API you *can* *add* entries to the Environment variables. You can *replace* all of them *or* use the default).

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thank you very much. Now I understood better the difference between ProcessBuilder and Runtime.

Comment: I can no longer edit it, but "in the `Runtime.exec()` API you *can add* entries" is missing a *not*.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the javadoc for java.lang.Runtime#exec and java.lang.ProcessBuilder.