# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec on Windows error

Tags: java, networking, exec, runtime.exec, nmap

I am trying to run this line of code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24", g});
```

The above gives this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at Test.main(Test.java:14)
```

However, this line of code works fine:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"nmap", g});
```

Here are some particulars:

- Installed *nmap 5.51* which works perfectly from the 'cmd line'.
- *Windows Vista*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute command with parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134486/how-to-execute-command-with-parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using this code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"nmap", "-sP", "192.168.1.0/24", g});
```

this is equivalent to:

```
"nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24".split(" ");
```

The first entry in the array is always the file, and anything after that is parameters.
What it was doing was looking for "nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24" as a program, with no parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("nmap", "-sP", "192.168.1.0/24");
 Process p = pb.start();
```

Basically you have to separate the program from its arguments.