# java process: file not found

Tags: java, file

While executing the following code it gives a file not found error at a:28 (in comments). Is it because of directory is not refreshed, or the file not created by subprocess before executing line at a:28?

```
File outputFile = new File("RunstatsCmd.db2");
FileWriter out = new FileWriter(outputFile);

String cmd = "DB2CMD;DB2;"+" EXPORT TO "+ "\"C:\\file.xml\"" +" OF IXF MESSAGES "+"\"C:\\msg.txt\""+" SELECT * FROM OLTP.ACCOUNT_DETAILS";

out.write("CONNECT TO OLTPDB;\n");
out.write(cmd + ";\n");
out.write("CONNECT RESET;\n");

out.close();

System.out.println("before creating connection....");
Class.forName ("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver").newInstance ();
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("db2 -vtf RunstatsCmd.db2");

// open streams for the process's input and error                                       
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
                                      InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
                                      InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
String s;

// read the output from the command and set the output variable with 
// the value
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(s);
}

// read any errors from the attempted command and set the error  
// variable with the value
while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) 
{
    System.out.println(s);
}

// destroy the process created 


// delete the temporary file created
outputFile.deleteOnExit(); 


System.out.println("query executed...");   
p.waitFor();        
//a:28////////////////////////                  
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("C:\\file.xml");
int i;
while((i=fis.read())!=-1){
    System.out.println((char)i);
}

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Aside from your file problems, your `exec()` isn't going to work either - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134486/how-to-execute-command-with-parameters

Answer (score 1):

Backslashes in strings need to be escaped.

```
"C:\\file.xml"
```

Alternatively, use forward slashes (they're accepted in Java, even on Windows machines).

```
"C:/file.xml"
```

Comment: It's funny, he does this up top, but not at the bottom.

Comment: I guess it's easy enough to miss even if you are aware of the need.

Comment: Especially when you happen to hit a valid escape sequence like `\f` so the compiler doesn't remind you.

Answer (score 0):

In a java String, `\` is an *escape character*, and so it must be escaped if you want to use it literally.

So to represent *C:\file.xml*, you'll need to use this java String: `"C:\\file.xml"`.

But note that in java you can always use forward slashes as path separators - even in windows - so this should also work:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/file.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `\` character carefully when using for `file path`.

Change your code to this:

```
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("C:\\file.xml");
```

`\` is a escape character.

Alternatively you can use:

```
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("C:/file.xml");
```