# How to pass parameter to shell script in java program

Tags: java, bash, shell

i am trying to run this java code that calls the shell script on runtime.

when i run the script in terminal i am passing argument to script

code:

```
./test.sh argument1
```

java code:

```
public class scriptrun
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
            {
            try
                {
                    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./test.sh");
                    System.out.println("Print Test Line.");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
```

How to pass argument for script in java code?

Comment: Use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute command with parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134486/how-to-execute-command-with-parameters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preferred way to create processes in recent versions of Java is to use the [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class, which makes this very simple:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("./test.sh", "kstc-proc");
// set the working directory here for clarity, as you've used a relative path
pb.directory("foo");
Process proc = pb.start();
```

But if you do want to/need to use `Runtime.exec` for whatever reason, there are [overloaded versions of that method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) that allow the arguments to be specified explicitly:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"./test.sh", "kstc-proc"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something very simple you can try

```
public class JavaRunCommandExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = null;
        String cmd[] = {"./test.sh","argument1"};

        try {
            p = r.exec(cmd);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```