# Running Unix Command in Java File

Tags: java, unix, sed, command-prompt

I was trying to run a unix command in java to overlook the double quotation mark in a parsed file:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < numTables; i++){
        try{
            String command = "sed -e \'s/\"/\"\"/g\' -e \'s/^/\"/\' -e \'s/$/\"/\' -e \'s/<>/\"<>\"/g\' input.dat > output.dat";
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        } catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println("Error executing command");
        }
    }
```

However, typing the identical command on the terminal directly would work.
Any idea what went wrong?
Thank you!

Update:
In fact, I tried the following (using array instead of just a String), it failed too:

```
            String[] command = new String[] {"sed", "-e", "\'s/\"/\"\"/g\'", "-e", "\'s/^/\"/\'", "-e", "\'s/$/\"/\'", "-e", "\'s/<>/\"<>\"/g\'", prefixedFileList.get(i), ">", fileList.get(i)};
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Any thoughts?

As a clearer picture, the corresponding plain text that would be executed on unix terminal would be

```
sed -e 's/"/""/g' -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/$/"/' -e 's/<>/"<>"/g' input.dat > output.dat
```

Comment: How did it fail? Did you get an error, or simply nothing happened?

Comment: Get the process's output stream and print it. Possibly the error should be exposed there.

Comment: Looking for something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134486/how-to-execute-command-with-parameters

Comment: @Renan: Nothing happened

Comment: Perhaps you could go back and accept the answers to your previous questions.

Answer (score 0):

Well in some special character you are not putting \ ? Can you put the same.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to distinguish exactly what a program argument is.  When you execute this line:

```
sed -e 's/"/""/g' -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/$/"/' -e 's/<>/"<>"/g' input.dat > output.dat
```

The `main` method of the **sed** binary receives these strings in its argv:

- `sed`
- `-e`
- `s/"/""/g`
- `-e`
- `s/^/"/`
- `-e`
- `s/$/"/`
- `-e`
- `s/<>/"<>"/g`
- `input.dat`

Notice that the single-quotes (`'`) are not part of the program arguments.  The single-quotes are interpreted by the shell (bash, csh, etc.).  They tell the shell not to evaluate or parse what's inside them.  The shell takes a single-quoted string and passes it to the program as is, but the single-quotes are not part of the argument.  They are for the benefit of the shell only.

Also notice that the file redirection, `> output.dat`, is not part of the program arguments.  File redirection is parsed by the shell.  It is not a program's job to know whether its standard output is being redirected;  the program writes to standard output regardless, and the operating system performs the redirection.  If you try to pass `> output.dat` as program arguments, **sed** will look for an additional input file named `>` and an additional input file named `output.dat`.

It is always better to call a Runtime.exec method which takes an array rather than a single String, as you seem to already know.  Even better than that is to use the [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class, which can do output redirection, essentially duplicating the functionality of `>` in the shell:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
    "sed",
    "-e",
    "s/\"/\"\"/g",
    "-e",
    "s/^/\"/",
    "-e",
    "s/$/\"/",
    "-e",
    "s/<>/\"<>\"/g",
    "input.dat");
builder.redirectOutput(new File("output.dat"));
builder.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);

Process p = builder.start();
```

Comment: This seems to be a pretty legitimate answer. However, when I tried, it still fails........... :(

Comment: How does it fail?  Are you seeing an exception?

Comment: Try adding `builder.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);` so any errors displayed by **sed** are visible in your program's output.  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best solutions it to use [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html) library.

Below is my favourite usage :

```
CommandLine cmdLine = new CommandLine("AcroRd32.exe");
cmdLine.addArgument("/p");
cmdLine.addArgument("/h");
DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
executor.setExitValue(1);
int exitValue = executor.execute(cmdLine);
```

We don't have to worry about encapsulating arguments properly using this form.