# not able to execute rsync from java

Tags: java, linux, ssh, rsync

```
 Process p;
 String cmd = "rsync --timeout=20 -v -r -E -e \"ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i "
                      + "/usr/local/my.pem\"" 
                      + " root@<IP>:/usr/local/test/ /other/test";
try {
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    System.out.println("going to exec1");
    int val = p.waitFor();  
    }
```

When i try the above code, `rsync` does not work and `val` = `1`.

while if i try `cmd` value directly on `ternimal` it works fine.

What is wrong with the code ?

---

Edited

```
String[] cmd = new String[]{"rsync", "--timeout=20", "-v", "-r", "-a", "-E", "-e",
                        "\"ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i " + "/usr/local/my.pem" + "\"",
                         "root" + "@" + "198.168.1.3" + ":" + "/usr/local/test1" ,
                        "/usr/local" + "/" + "test1"};

    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        System.out.println("going to exec1");
        int val = p.waitFor();  
        }
```

This time `val` = `12`
Now what can be wrong

Comment: Augusto is right. Also remember that javas Runtime.exec does not interpolate shell metacharacters.

Comment: Remove the `\"` characters you're adding around the ssh command. You only need quotes on a shell command line to tell the shell where the word boundaries are, with the multi-arg `exec` you've already done the word splitting yourself. As written now you're telling rsync to use a command named doublequote-s-s-h which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a different version of `exec`, as the one you're using assumes that the command **name** is the whole string.

You need to use [this flavor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) of `exec`, which takes a string array, where each element in the array is one of the parameters.

If fact, this question is a duplicate of [How to execute command with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134486/how-to-execute-command-with-parameters) (where you can see an example)