# Java main argument identified as main class

Tags: java, cmd, arguments, program-entry-point

I have a problem running a Java process with arguments as a command from another Java manager process. Say I have a main class **Main**, and I want to pass **0** as an argument (for javaw.exe it's just one of the arguments). To illustrate, if I run something like this in a console, it works:

```
javaw.exe -X... -D... -cp ... Main 0
```

This runs Main with the argument 0. Now, to run this from my manager application I use the following line:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new string[] {
    "cmd.exe", "/c", "javaw.exe", "-X... -D... -cp ... Main", "0"});
```

I get the following output in *err*:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class 0
```

In other words, the JVM identifies the 0 as the main class.
Using a different exec overloading is not a recommended option (it's a generic infrastructure).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134486/how-to-execute-command-with-parameters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well you're passing the whole of "-X... -D... -cp ... Main" as a single argument. Instead, you should have:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new string[] {
    "cmd.exe", "/c", "javaw.exe", "-X...", "-D...", "-cp", "...", "Main", "0"});
```

Comment: Right. Didn't know it mattered... Thnx.