# how to overcome keyboard enter in java execution

Tags: java

I want to run this code in java using:

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(str);  
"cmd /c WMIC CPU GET LoadPercentage  > n.txt";
```

If I use it in a bat file, there is no problem.
But if I put it into a Java, it just keep running until break.
Does anyone have a solution?
Running windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute command with parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134486/how-to-execute-command-with-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the String in the .exec() parameters into multiple strings with no spaces, like this:

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd", "/c", "WMIC", "CPU", "GET", "LoadPercentage", ">", "n.txt"});
```

Answer (score 0):

And not!
I have put the above exec cmd into two bat-files in order to get a result.
Unfortunately the result first come out when I teminate the program.
For clarity: The above code is running in a "prochrun, Apace".
The first request is to get the PID using "Tasklist", that comes out with a response, working fine.
But when I request a "cmd /c WMIC CPU GET LoadPercentage  > n.txt" inside another bat-file, I first get the response when I kill the process.
How do I get the response inside a running program running procrun?
Br