# Run .sh File in Java Code on Linux Machine

Tags: java, linux, shell, sql-loader

***My Task:***
1 - Read an Excel File, parse it and save the data in txt file.
2 - Read that txt file and pass it to a *batch.sh* file. This *batch.sh* file do one thing, it picks the data from the above mentioned txt file and save it in a database's table.

When I run the batch.sh file from the terminal(and give it the txt file), it works fine. It inserts the records in the database just as i want.

***Problem is***, when I want to do the same with the java code, the *batch.sh* file does not work. And also, no exception is thrown.

***Some Explanation:*** I am using Java 7, Oracle, SQL-Loader, Linux.

***Additional Information:*** If I rename the batch.sh file to batch.bat file and run it in Windows environment, it works perfectly fine. the batch.sh file also works fine if it is executed from the terminal. The only problem is, its not working from java code.

I am listing the java code snippet, batch.sh file and the control.txt file for the following task.

***Java Code:***

```
try{
    String target = new String("/path/to/batchFile/batch.sh");
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = rt.exec(target);
    proc.waitFor(); 
}catch(Exception e){
    LOG.error("Exception Occured with Message : "+e.getMessage());
}
```

***Batch.sh:***

```
sqlldr username/password@sid control='/path/to/batchFile/control.txt' log='/path/to/batchFile/Results.log' bad='/path/to/batchFile/BadFile.bad' ERRORS=5000
```

***control.txt:***

```
options  ( skip=1 )
load data
  infile               '/path/to/batchFile/TxtFileData.txt'           
  truncate into table   TABLE_NAME
fields terminated by ","       

  (  
  column_name "replace(:column_name,'-','')"    
  )
```

***P.S:*** I have read many post regarding the same issue, and tried every solution, but non is working. The current example of java code is taken from another StackOverFlow thread.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want `runtime.getRuntime.exec(new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c", "/path/to/script.txt"})`
See here: [How to execute command with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134486/how-to-execute-command-with-parameters)

Comment: Thank you for taking out time for the response. Just for a quick thought... Can u please tell me the what are the 3 string parameters representing?

Comment: 3rd parameter seems to be the absolute path with file name...but what about the 1rst and 2nd parameter? What do they represent?

Comment: My apologies. /bin/bash is the shell interpreter, and everything after that is an argument, so it's equivalent to running /bin/bash -c /path/to/your/script.txt or whatever, and the reason we're doing that is because when you're in a shell, sh files are automatically executed by bash, whereas java's runtime execution service does not. So you're telling it explicitly to run it. You mght actually need to remove -c though, it depends on what the context is, eg: /bin/bash -c ping -n google.com is fine, but an actual script ight be /bin/bash /path/to/script.sh and work, i forget.

Comment: Thank you Zack for your time and the explanation. The command worked, but there was another tweak that i found was necessary to run the batch.sh file. I was not using the *'#!/bin/bash*' in the start of batch file. Marking it as a correct answer.

Comment: I have posted another question related to linux. If u get some time, please have a look into it and guide if possible... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676310/run-as-other-user-option-in-linux