# Run as Other user Option in Linux

Tags: java, linux, bash, sql-loader

***Case :***

My case is pretty straight forward. I have a Linux server machine. On that server, there are 2 users. One is ***root*** and the other is ***oracle***. Now here is the thing, the root user does not know the ***sqlldr*** command, this command is recognized by ***oracle*** user only.

I have a ***batch.sh*** file and in that file i have an ***sqlldr*** command that will insert record in the database. When i open terminal using ***oracle*** user, that ***batch.sh*** file runs according to the expectations. But when I run that batch file from terminal using the ***root*** user, it says "***./batch.sh: line 3: sqlldr: command not found***".

***Problem:***

Now the problem is, I am calling this batch.sh file from java code, and this java process is started as ***root***. There is no way for me to switch this java process to oracle. However what I am expecting is, that i may switch user before executing the command in the ***batch.sh*** file using the ***root*** user.

Here is my batch.sh file content.

```
#!/bin/bash

sqlldr username/password@sid control='/path/toFile/control.txt' log='/path/toFile/Results.log' bad='/path/toFile/BadFile.bad' ERRORS=5000

exit 0
```

I am expecting something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

### Start - Switch user here from root to oracle so that it recognize the following command

sqlldr username/password@sid control='/path/toFile/control.txt' log='/path/toFile/Results.log' bad='/path/toFile/BadFile.bad' ERRORS=5000

### End - Undo the switch that we made above

exit 0
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Also see [How to have MySQL entitle the machine's root user?](http://superuser.com/q/1060360) on Super User.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144832/how-can-i-run-as-another-user. You don't change users in a script, but you can have your script run a command that runs another command or script as the user you specify.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a duplicate of a question on another site.

Comment: Running your Java as `root` is not a good idea in the first place. Make a dedicated user and sort out permissions in the operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also have root run the command as that user in your script with [runuser](https://linux.die.net/man/1/runuser):

```
runuser -l oracle -c "sqlldr username/password@sid control='/path/toFile/control.txt' log='/path/toFile/Results.log' bad='/path/toFile/BadFile.bad' ERRORS=5000"
```

Comment: Ohh boy, did you solve my problem :) ...  Really really great-full to your advice and time ... it solved my problem and saved my day...

Answer (score 1):

The executable sqlldr is simply not in the root's search PATH. So, when you are logged in as root, you will not be able to execute sqlldr.

What you need to do is find out where sqlldr is located (eg. /folderof/yourtool) and do A or B:
A) make sure you include it in the root path that is loaded when root logs in, using the method according to your linux distribution 
or 
B) add the line `PATH=$PATH:/folderof/yourtool` to the shell script or java environment to dynamically add the PATH.

Comment: thank u for the time.. but the Zack answer solved the problem.