# How to execute windows commands with java program in windows OS

Tags: java, gradle

I want to gradle build on a huge set of projects to import into the eclipse. I know that, we can include the projects which we want to build under `settings.gradle` file. But there is a limitation with this in my working area.

So what I thought is, instead of doing the gradle build by going to each and every project. I want to automate this with the java program.

I tried to execute the basic windows command execution with the following java program:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;      
public class Windows {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Windows obj = new Windows();    

        String output = obj.executeCommand("ipconfig");

        System.out.println(output);

    }

    private String executeCommand(String command) {

        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader =
                            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return output.toString();    
    }
}
```

So, In the above program if I give the command as `gradle build` it is not working
Can you please help me on this.

Comment: see this question and it's accepted answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134486/how-to-execute-command-with-parameters

Comment: I have to really ask why? Why not simply use scripting support for your platform? Batch scripting for Windows and shell scripting for Linux?

Comment: As I said, there is a limitation with the multi-project build in my working area due to svn hookup, I am not able to compile successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using Gradle, why not solve this in gradle?

Option 1: Put everything in a [multi-project build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html)

Option 2: Create a [composite build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) from multiple separate builds

Option 3: Create an "uber" gradle build which invokes the others using a [GradleBuild](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.GradleBuild.html) task

```
apply plugin: 'base'

def buildDirs = ['dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3']

buildDirs.each { buildDir ->
   Task task = tasks.create(name: "build${buildDir.capitialize()}", type: GradleBuild) {
      dir = buildDir
      tasks = ['build']
   }
   build.dependsOn task
}
```

Comment: Gradle has subprojects, so he can build a dependency graph wtih gradle with various tasks associated at the high level.

Comment: I believe he (she?) wants to keep separate builds rather than a single multi-module build. Which is why composite build or `GradleBuild` are the options

Comment: As I said, there is a limitation with the multi-project build in my working area due to svn hookup, I am not able to compile successfully