# Curl command that makes a GET request to a server works within Terminal but not in java code

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a localhost server using jersey that acts as my API, when I issue a curl GET request within command line i get the expected result but, when i do the same within Java i get a 404 error.

I have the code under a jButtonActionPerformed button where the user presses a button to issue the curl command, what is very strange is if i click the button repeatedly i eventually get the response i am looking for however the first click always returns a 404 error. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Code

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = rt.exec("curl -i -H \"Accept: application/json\" -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -X GET http://localhost:8080/api/products/1");
        String result = new BufferedReader(
                       new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))
                           .lines()
                           .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        System.out.println(result);


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GetDetailsGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: try using the parameter list for exec method

Comment: Can you give an example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134486/how-to-execute-command-with-parameters

Comment: Try this, Process p = rt.exec(new String[] {"curl", "-i", "-H", "\"Accept: application/json\"", "-H", "\"Content-Type: application/json\"", "-X", "GET", "http://localhost:8080/api/products/1"});

Comment: Just tried it, same scenario, on the first few button clicks i get a 404 error and then eventually after several clicks i get the returned response