# Running a adb command programatically Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, adb

I am trying to run a adb command programatically in Android before I run a test case. But I get the following exception

`runShellCommand exception - Error running exec(). Command: [adb, shell, settings, put, secure, immersive_mode_confirmations, confirmed] Working Directory: null Environment: null`

```
  private void runShellCommand(String command) {
        Timber.d("runShellCommand");
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            Timber.d("runShellCommand exception - " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

this is how I call that function with the adb command

```
runShellCommand("adb shell settings put secure immersive_mode_confirmations confirmed");
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this please

Thanks
R

Comment: I think you should pass the parameters as an array, take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134486/how-to-execute-command-with-parameters

Comment: hey I tried that but got the same error - `Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"adb","shell", "settings", "put", "secure", "immersive_mode_confirmations", "confirmed"});
            process.waitFor();`

Comment: seems you need root

Comment: Try something like this: `Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash","-c", command});             process.waitFor();` if you are using GNU/Linux.